# angularjs ng-click ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this code to open a modal inside a ng-repeat. The modal is working fine as long as I hardcode the Id. However I would like to open another modal if it's for record 2, 3, etc.

```
        <div class="w3-container w3-center w3-yellow">
      <!-- Trigger/Open the Modal -->
      <button onclick="document.getElementById('{{ x.Id }}').style.display='block'"
      class="w3-button">Meer foto's</button>
    </div>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="{{ x.Id }}" class="w3-modal">
      <div class="w3-modal-content">
        <div class="w3-container">
          <span onclick="document.getElementById('1002').style.display='none'"
          class="w3-button w3-display-topright w3-red">&times;</span>
            <div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin">
                <div class="w3-third">
                  <div class="w3-card-2">
                    <img src="/administratie/assets/uploads/files/{{ x.Foto_1 }}" style="width:100%">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-third">
                  <div class="w3-card-2">
                    <img src="/administratie/assets/uploads/files/{{ x.Foto_2 }}" style="width:100%">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-third">
                  <div class="w3-card-2">
                    <img src="/administratie/assets/uploads/files/{{ x.Foto_3 }}" style="width:100%">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-row-padding w3-margin">
                <div class="w3-third">
                  <div class="w3-card-2">
                    <img src="/administratie/assets/uploads/files/{{ x.Foto_4 }}" style="width:100%">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-third">
                  <div class="w3-card-2">
                    <img src="/administratie/assets/uploads/files/{{ x.Foto_5 }}" style="width:100%">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-third">
                  <div class="w3-card-2">
                    <img src="/administratie/assets/uploads/files/{{ x.Foto_6 }}" style="width:100%">
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

onclick is not accepted however I can't make the ng-click working either. Can someone please give me some hints how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

First don't use onclick if you are using angularjs, use ng-click.

Second don't hide elements with pure javascript/jQuery by manipulating DOM elements, you are using AngularJS do it AngularJS way that being ng-show.

For simple purposes I will say you have 2 buttons one will show something one will close something. So on first button (open button) you should use `ng-click="isShowing=true"` and on second one (close button) will have`ng-click="isShowing=false"`

Then use `ng-show="isShowing"` which will set div to visible/hidden on whatever element you want to show. Keep in mind as long as button is not pressed isShowing property doesn't exist it will be undefined - falsy and it will not show, after click it will be set to true and show the div, then if you click on other button for closing it should set it to false and hide the div.

On your particular example on button that should show modal:

```
<button ng-click="isShowing=true" class="w3-button">Meer foto's</button>
```

and then on modal div:

```
<div id="{{ x.Id }}" ng-show="isShowing" class="w3-modal">
```

and in the end closing span:

```
 <span ng-click="isShowing=false" class="w3-button w3-display-topright w3-red">&times;</span>
```

Keep in mind if you have some bad CSS styles this can interfere with the showing/hiding. And I would recommend this read as I can see you come from vanillaJS/jQuery background:
https://gabrieleromanato.name/introduction-to-angularjs-for-jquery-developers